# Jenkins makefile error

Tags: c++, linux, windows, jenkins, makefile

I am setting up CI for my project, the build works fine on linux but on windows it shows `Makefile:84: *** missing separator.  Stop.`. What's interesting to see here is the same Makefile works fine on the local machine but not through Jenkins.

i have checked the character set and converted the file to UTF8-Without BOM but that doesn't seem to work.

Any direction to this ? If the makefiles for windows and linux is different than whats the difference there which could cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your line endings are set correctly. Also make sure you use tabs and spaces as appropriate.

Check the versions of `make` with `make --version` - it might give you some hints.

Apart from that, we can only guess what is on line 84 :)